# Nested routes form is performing a get request for the index action instead of the create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app and I have nested routes like so

```
resources :teams, shallow: true do
  resources :texts
  resources :translations
end
```

here is my app/texts.show.html.erb.My app has texts and each text has a translation and each translation belongs to a text.When I click on a text I am taken to the texts show page where I have a form for a translator.The translator can translate the text.Each translation and text belongs to a team so that I can show specific texts and translations for specific teams.However the form below seems to be doing a get request for the index action.That is the error I am getting and I can't figure out why.Maybe something very obvious I am missing.

```
<% if current_user.translator %>
  <%= form_for [@team, @translation] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :translation_text, :placeholder => 'Çeviri' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :text_id, :value => params[:id] %>
    <%= f.submit 'Çevir', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Here is my translations_controller.rb file

```
  def create
    team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    @translation = team.translations.new(translation_params)
    @translation.user_id = current_user.id
    if @translation.save
      redirect_to request.original_url, success: 'Çeviri tamalandı'
    else
      redirect_to request.original_url, danger: 'Çeviri sırasında sorun oluştu lütfen tekrar dene'
    end
  end

  private

  def translation_params
    params.require(:translation).permit(:team_id, :text_id, :translation_text)
  end
```

Could the problem be that I am in texts#show and am doing something wrong with the form?

Comment: Are you sure your JavaScript is working?

Comment: so what exactly is the error you are getting? i think that this article is worth a read: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: The error I am getting is this        AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
The action 'index' could not be found for TranslationsController.It is  going for the index action when it should be going for create

Comment: you could specify the method to use in the form_for tag e.g. `form_for [@team, @translation], method: :post` this will look for a post route which would be the create method.